# Drawing EditText onto canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-edittext

I am trying to draw many edittext on canvas every time when the user draw a rectangle using the ondraw on the canvas. Is this even possible? without having to add the edittext on the xml file? and also i an trying to do this in a java file instead of the activity. Please advice thank you.

Current draw rectangle codes are as follows:

```
 for (RectF rec : rects) {

    if (rec.height() != 50 ) {
        canvas.drawOval(rec, paintColor);

    } else {
        canvas.drawRect(rec, paintColor);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to draw text on your canvas, you can call:

```
canvas.drawText()
```

Comment: But the text could not be change right? I would want the user to be able to make changes to the text.

Comment: You could have the view define an interface with a method that is called every time a rectangle is drawn on the canvas.

For example:
`private interface CanvasRectListener {
     private void onRectDrawn(float x, float y, float width, float height);
}`

Then create a new listener in the fragment where the view is created. Every time onRectDrawn is called, you could programmatically add a new edit text.

Comment: do you have any tutorials or reference i can refer to?

Comment: Check out: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.newedittext, null);

 
       
EditText editText = (EditText)addView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);         editTextList.add(editText);         MainLayout.addView(addView);

I manage to add the editText but how to ensure that is lay nicely below the rectangle drawn? and it could move with the rectangles on the canvas?

Comment: You will have to programmatically set the EditText's LayoutParams  based on the x, y values of the rectangle.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781286/how-to-poistion-edittext-in-program-in-android

Comment: @TimothyMiko is there any way to set a functionable edit text onto canvas rather than just drawing an edit text field?